Will adding full-wave rectifier make LED Christmas lights brighter?
I have some LED Christmas light strings that are powered from 120VAC. They have 60 LEDS consisting of two parallel 30 bulb sections & no rectifiers. The sections are wired opposite polarity so that 30 LEDs conduct on the positive portion of the sine wave & 30 on the negative.
The C6 style bulbs are replaceable. You can then separate the base from the strawberry "lens". Inside is a 3mm LED that emits a colored light which matches the lens. Some of the LEDs have a small resistor attached to one lead which fits inside the bulb's base. You have no idea it's there unless you remove the lens & remove the LED from the base.
I thought about adding some diodes & converting each section to full-wave. But I’m not sure how to calculate the LED current since they do not conduct for all of the half wave portion.

Since the LEDs are on for only a small time, would supplying them full wave current make them brighter without the risk of burning them out? IOW is the duty cycle of full wave vs. half wave going to be detrimental to the LED?

Since the LEDs only turn on when the voltage reaches a certain level, I'm presuming that Peak Volt x .318 probably will not apply for average DC. How would I calculate the current?

Is 20mA average DC of an AC supply even the same as steady 20mA DC from an LED's perspective?


More info -
The Kill-A-Watt meter indicates 40mA draw on the whole string. If I remove an LED from one section it kills that section, and the remaining 30 LED section shows 20mA on the Kill-A-Watt meter. Since the LEDs are only conducting on half of the sine wave, is the meter still reading an RMS value for current? Or is reading an average DC value and converting that to RMS?

LED's do not last long when average current is increased. Cheap LED's in series lighting are even more likely to fail that way. To quote Milay, https://poets.org/poem/first-fig, "My candle burns at both ends;
It will not last the night..."


To a reasonable approximation, you will double the average currect.  Because the LEDs will now conduct on both half-cycles, instead of only one.  We don't know if it will burn out the LEDs, without knowing what the current is now.

Assuming they are 3V LEDs, that's about 90V per string before they turn on.  120V AC peaks at about 170V.  The hidden resistors will limit the current as it goes above 90V, so they are important to stop the whole lot burning out.  Given that the resistors are there, it's not going to be easy to calculate the average current.  Measuring it makes more sense.

Yes, close enough.



(Unless the strings are antiparallel to begin with.)
